# Import/export falla al ejecutar Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, importación

Estoy intentado exportar una constante en un archivo js e importarlo en otro js. No me está funcionando, porque me salta un error de CORS, el código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- <script type="module" src="heroes.js"></script> -->
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

index.js

```js
import { heroesVariable } from './heroes.js';

console.log(heroesVariable);
```

heroes.js

```js
export const heroesVariable = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Batman',
        owner: 'DC'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Spiderman',
        owner: 'Marvel'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Superman',
        owner: 'DC'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Flash',
        owner: 'DC'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Wolverine',
        owner: 'Marvel'
    },
];
```

Error =>

```
Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/xxx/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

No se si mi fallo está en que no he realizado bien el import del js en el html, o sin embargo no está correctamente realizada la importación.

Comment: Hola Luis, ¿estás ejecutando de manera local este archivo JS? Sólo un servidor HTTP podrá responder a peticiones HTTP, por lo que intentar cargar un fichero local fallará siempre, incluso si el fichero Javascript no tuviese el problema de CORS. Una solución es quitar este "bloqueo" desde la consola de comandos del navegador (lo cual sólo está recomendado para desarrolladores) otra solución es crear un servidor local y desde ahí ejecutar tu página.

Comment: Lo estoy ejecutando localmente, entonces si me dices que tengo que tener un servidor, me gustaría al menos saber si de la forma que lo he hecho funcionaria...